# R : Difference in joins : Dplyr and sql

Tags: r, oracle, dplyr, odbc, r-dbi

I would like to understand the difference between dplyr joins and sql joins.
I have an open connection to an **oracle** database in R:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), …)
```

The 1st request :

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select * 
   from result join test on result.test_1 = test.test_1 
   join sample on test.sample = sample.id_2") %>% 
   setNames(make.names(names(.), unique = TRUE) )%>% 
   as_tibble()
```

gives a tibble with **9541 rows** (what I want !)

The 2nd request :

```
tbl(con, "result")%>%
   inner_join(tbl(con, "sample"), by = c("test_1" = "id_2"))%>%
   collect()
```

gives a tibble with **2688 rows**

test_1 and id_2 are character fields with spaces in it and numbers  at the end. example: “     3333” .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL I see 3 tables, in R I see 2 tables : result and sample table.

Here is the probable cause of the difference.

Comment: yes you are right, I simply forgot one join with a third table "test" :   tbl(con, "RESULT") %>%
      inner_join(tbl(con, "TEST"), by = c("TEST_1" = "TEST_1")) %>% 
      inner_join(tbl(con, "SAMPLE") , by = c("SAMPLE" = "ID_2"))